# Images rotating when uploaded only on iOS flutter

Tags: flutter, dart

the images are randomly rotating when being uploaded. For android it's not an issue but it is for iOS so I tried this to fix it. but it doesn't work on most pictures:

```
changeAvatarImage() async {
    XFile? pickedFile = await ImagePicker().pickImage(
        source: ImageSource.gallery,
        maxHeight: 1800,
        maxWidth: 1800,
        requestFullMetadata: true);

    if (pickedFile != null) {
      File rotatedFile = await FlutterExifRotation.rotateImage(
        path: pickedFile.path,
      );
      await socialService.uploadImage(XFile(rotatedFile.path));
      avatarFile.value = rotatedFile;
      localStorageService.saveXFileToLocalStorage(
          'avatar_image', XFile(rotatedFile.path));
    }
  }
```

Comment: use flutter_exif_rotation package.

Comment: this is using that. but it doesn't work for iOS